# GCC : C++11 inline object initialization (using "this") does not work when there is a virtual inheritance in hierarchy

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, virtual

C++11 inline object initialization does not work (in GCC) when this pointer is used in initialization and there is a virtual inheritance in hierarchy.
Can this be a bug is GCC (because it works in CLang)? Or a gap in C++11 standard itself?

Example (one can try it in [here](https://rextester.com/HZNOM87919)), when below code is compiled with GCC:

```
FieldIndex m_inB{"inB", this};
```

does not get executed.
But it gets executed when compiled with CLang.

WORK AROUND : Derive A from `FieldIndexContainer` as virtual

```
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
using namespace std;

class FieldIndexContainer
{
public:
    class FieldIndex
    {
    public:
        FieldIndex( const std::string& fieldName, FieldIndexContainer* owner) 
        {
            cout << "FieldIndex called = " << fieldName << endl;
        }
    };  
};

class A : public FieldIndexContainer
{
public:
    FieldIndex m_inA{ "inA", this};
};

class Mid : virtual public A {};

class B : virtual public Mid
{
public:     
    FieldIndex m_inB{"inB", this};
};

int main () 
{
    B* b = new B;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: By "does not work", do you mean it won't compile (in which case [edit] your question to include the compiler error) or that it doesn't give the expected result (in which case [edit] your question to include the actual and expected outputs)?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm not working, as not calling the constructor of the member at runtime

Comment: Looks as a gcc bug to me

Comment: I like the compiler output of `"virtual_gcc_bug.cpp:27:7: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your MCVE can be further reduced.

There is no need for **`class Mid`**. **`class B`** can be **`virtual public`** inherited from **`class A`** and the problem still exists.

Apart from the workaround you have proposed of deriving **`A`** from **`FieldIndexContainer`** as **`virtual`**, the code also **works correctly without any `virtual` inheritance at all**.

See [Live Demo 1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/c0UwDbE7GXx6zG37).

With member initialization the code works correctly without any workaround.

See [Live Demo 2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ONeoiYUGerKDTXob).

So, this is a GCC bug.

There was a bug report raised for GCC titled: [Missing default initialization of member when combined with virtual inheritance](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=68903) which is very similar to what you are observing with your code.

Answer (score 1):

GCC fails to call the constructor of the member `m_inB`. There is no possible case in C++ when an object is constructed successfully, but one of its members isn't.

This is a bug in GCC.